# Lorentzian analogue to Thurston geometries

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, 3-manifolds, semi-riemannian-geometry, lorentzian-geometry

Is there an analogue to the eight [Thurston geometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture#The_eight_Thurston_geometries) for Lorentz metrics?

If so, how many "disctinct" geometries are there in the Lorentzian case?

And which closed 3-manifolds admit metrics which are locally modelled on one of those lorentzian model geometries?

Comment: Both questions are answered here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10711-010-9480-0

https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2737692

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you know of any english reference for this?

Comment: Have you tried Google translate? It's pretty good, except for the formatting. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6dgppxud4ot1g7/Lorentzian%20geometries%20of%20dimension%203-%20classification%20and%20completeness.pdf?dl=0

Comment: No I have actually never tried that on a math paper. But I will give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: @IanAgol could you make answer from your comment, so the question will be removed from unanswered list?

Answer (score 7):

Both questions are answered here:

*Dumitrescu, Sorin; Zeghib, Abdelghani*, [**Three-dimensional Lorentz geometries: Classification and completeness**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10711-010-9480-0), Geom. Dedicata 149, 243-273 (2010). [ZBL1216.53025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1216.53025).